# How to convert raw SQL query into Silverstripe SQLQuery abstraction layer

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, silverstripe

I have a page that I'm trying to pull articles related the page from a database.  I have the SQL query that pulls what I need but I keep getting the error "Unknown column 'Fashion' in 'where clause'".  I believe I need to convert it from,

```
$FilteredStories =  DB::query(' SELECT C.ID, C.URLSegment, C.Title, B.Title AS "Category"
                                FROM `articlepage_categories` AS A
                                JOIN articlecategory AS B ON A.ArticleCategoryID = B.ID
                                JOIN sitetree AS C ON A.ArticlePageID = C.ID
                                WHERE B.Title = "Fashion" LIMIT 5')
                    ->value();
```

into an SQLQuery abstraction layer but I don't know how. Can someone please show me how to create an SQLQuery abstraction layer with multiple joins?

**Notes**

- I'm using Silverstripe version 3.6.1
- "Fashion" is currently hard-coded but will be replaced with a
  variable that I'll pass in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SilverStripe's database uses `ANSI` `sql_mode` by default, in which string literals need to be surrounded by single quotes. You need to replace the double quotes surrounding `"Fashion"` with single quotes, like so:

```
$FilteredStories =  DB::query('SELECT C.ID, C.URLSegment, C.Title, B.Title AS "Category"
                            FROM `articlepage_categories` AS A
                            JOIN articlecategory AS B ON A.ArticleCategoryID = B.ID
                            JOIN sitetree AS C ON A.ArticlePageID = C.ID
                            WHERE B.Title = \'Fashion\' LIMIT 5')
```

Escaped here because outer quotes are single quotes.

And your query would be represented with an `SQLSelect` like so:

```
$filteredStories = SQLSelect::create();
$filteredStories->selectField('"sitetree"."ID", "sitetree"."URLSegment", "sitetree"."Title", "articlecategory"."Title" AS "Category"');
$filteredStories->setFrom('articlepage_categories');
$filteredStories->addLeftJoin('articlecategory', '"articlecategory"."ID" = "articlepage_categories"."ArticleCategoryID"');
$filteredStories->addLeftJoin('sitetree','"sitetree"."ID" = "articlepage_categories"."ArticlePageID"');
$filteredStories->addWhere('"articlecategory"."Title" = \'Fashion\'');
$filteredStories->setLimit(5);
```